# Error establishing a database connection : wordpress googleappengine cloudsql

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have DB connection error with ClouSQL. The details seems to be right.

`Error establishing a database connection`

Below is my connection details.

```
 define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/xxx-wp:wordpress');
  define('DB_USER', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

I am stuck with this for couple of days now, no clue what the reason. It works fine with my local.

When I try wordpress admin console, it displays this message. Here my connection details and all the scenarios mentioned here seem to be ok.

> This either means that the username and password information in your
>   wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database
>   server at :/cloudsql/vairagyawp:wordpress. This could mean your host's
>   database server is down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password? 
>   Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname? 
>   Are you sure that the database server is running?

Can you please clarify what the `wordpress` stands for in the DB_HOST detail. Is this CloudSQL instance name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason, **Cloud SQL Second Generation**  is still in beta. Doesn't support App Engine. Its there in the dropdown, check the attached screenshot.

[image]